# Print all the combinations of elements in a 2D Matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Print all the combinations of elements in matrix of size m * n.

Sample Example:
1   3   5
2   6   7

Expected Output:
2 , 1
2 , 3
2 , 5
6 , 1
6 , 3
6 , 5
7 , 1
7 , 3
7 , 5

Rules:
- Every combination starts from bottom of matrix and proceeds towards top. It may switch columns though.
- Every combination should have number of elements equal to number of rows.
- A combination can't have an element from the same row present twice.

I never could figure the solution out for general case. I can use 3 loops. But I want to understand the recursive solution. I use Java.

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also [this](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [this](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It's not a code request. I just want to understand how recursion can be used. No need to write any code.

Comment: I have a solution for an array of size 2,3. I use 3 loops for it. But as size increases, its not feasible. It's very naive.

Comment: Look for n choose k recursion with back tracking.

Comment: @abhyuditjain Can you explain this : _A combination can't have an element from the same row present twice_ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-recursive way to solve this problem (it's not all that pretty, but it works for your input). I know you were interested in recursion, but I don't have anything like that for you at the moment. Generally, I avoid recursion due to the size of problems I work with (constant heap space errors due to the size of the recursive stack even when `-Xmx60G`). Hope this helps.

```
private static List<int[]> combos;
public static void main(String[] args){
    combos = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    generate(new int[][]{{1,3,5},{2,6,7}});
    for(int[] s : combos){
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(s));
    }
}
private static void generate(int[][] elements) {
    int rows = elements.length;
    int[] elementsIndex = new int[rows];
    int[] elementsTotals = new int[rows];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(elementsTotals, elements[0].length);
    int curIdx = 0;
    int[] c = new int[rows];
    while(true){
        while(curIdx >= 0){
            if(curIdx == rows) {
                addCombo(c);
                curIdx--;
            }
            if(elementsIndex[curIdx] == elementsTotals[curIdx]){
                elementsIndex[curIdx] = 0;
                curIdx--;
            } else break;
        }
        if(curIdx < 0) break;
        // toggle order: 
        //  bottom up: elements[rows-curIdx-1][elementsIndex[curIdx]++]
        //  top down: elements[curIdx][elementsIndex[curIdx]++]
        c[curIdx] = elements[rows-curIdx-1][elementsIndex[curIdx]++];
        curIdx++;
    }
}
private static void addCombo(int[] c){
    int[] a = new int[c.length];
    System.arraycopy(c, 0, a, 0, c.length);
    combos.add(a);
}
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in one of the comments, this is for this particular input. What if the input size is large?

Comment: You can pass anything to the `generate` method and it will work. Try it for yourself.

Comment: All of these work: 
`generate(new int[][]{{1,3,5},{2,6,7}});
    generate(new int[][]{{1,3,5},{2,6,7},{8,9,0}});
    generate(new int[][]{{1,3,5,7},{2,6,7,1},{8,9,0,9}});
    generate(new int[][]{{1,3,5,7},{2,6,7,1},{8,9,0,9},{16,7,8,10}});`

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution would look something like this:

```
printPermutations(String head, Matrix m)
  if m is empty print head and return
  else for each item in last row of m
    printPermutations(head + item, m - bottom row)
```

here "head" is all the work we've done so far. In the body of a recursive method, there have to be at least two alternatives, one that outputs a result and ends the recursion, and one that goes deeper. For the deeper alternative, we transfer the selected element to `head`, remove the bottom row since we can't pick more than one item from any row, and do it again.

Done well, a recursive solution is often simpler and cleaner than using loops. On the other hand, recursion tends to use more memory